# Adding an open source license to a website with licensed images/names

Tags: licensing, license-recommendation, github, website, mpl

I have made one site and want to publish on GitHub, though this site has copyrighted images and names.

I've searched and found the MPL 2.0 that theoretically will protect this licensed images and names but I'm still not sure about it. I've read [the entire FAQ](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/FAQ/) and the [MPL 2.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/) but I didn't understood what it will protect for sure and where I have to [add the notices of copyright ownership that I have](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/FAQ/#:%7E:text=You%20may%20also%20add%20additional%20accurate%20notices,copyright%20holder%2C%20but%20this%20is%20not%20necessary).

Is any other open source license that allows other people to use the code of my site but not the images and names? Or every license is already like this?

I'm still new on the open source world so I don't really understand what other people will be able to use or not when I publish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Open Source Initiative website FAQs:
 https://opensource.org/faq#copying-and-identity

> **Does Open Source mean anybody else can use my name and logo?**
>
> No, at least not any more than they could otherwise. Open Source is about software source code, not about identity. That is, letting people use your code under an Open Source license is not the same as letting them use your trademarks or other identifying attributes, except insofar as they would be permitted to anyway (for example, in nominative use doctrine). There are many companies and other organizations that release open source code while exercising tight control over their trademarks.
>
> Trademarks and other marks of attribution are primarily about preventing public confusion over identity and provenance, and therefore trademark regulation is useful in Open Source software in the same way it is useful generally.

So the approved licenses they list should be ok if you want to keep exclusive rights of other content like images and names. And they list the MPL 2.0 license. It's independent, and you have to make sure they're licensed as you want. But I'm not a lawyer, I was just looking for the same information which I found there.